# Resetting variable at every workbook open

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro that draws a chart from given data. There's possibility that in the same workbook there will be made several more charts. I'd like to set chart to a certain place and make it certain size by using the same macro. The thing is, only thing I came up to to make this happen had this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").<whatever option goes here>
```

(or another number if it's next chart)

I'd like make it like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart " & x).<option>
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to make that `x` reset at every time I open the workbook to make it work properly. I kinda know it's related to `workbook_open()` and probably `Public x As Integer` but I have no idea how to put it together. I've tried some combinations of it but didn't work.

My whole code:

```
Sub import()


Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename

If Fname = False Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Arkusz2").Select
Columns("A:F").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.43

Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In Worksheets
    If wks.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        wks.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
Next wks





Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    Fname, Origin:=437 _
    , StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=","


Range("B1").Value = DateValue(Range("B1").Value)

Range("B4, B5, B6, B8").Activate
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Range("B21:C100").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000E+00"

Range("B2").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"




Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit


ark = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("import danych.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Arkusz2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select

Windows(ark).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.Close savechanges = True
Windows("import danych.xlsm").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Run "graph"




End Sub

Sub graph()



target = Range("B11").Value
dat = Range("B1").Value

Dim tim As Date
tim = Range("b2").Value
typ = Range("B7").Value

Cells.Find(What:="Ref signaal [A]", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

c = ActiveCell.Row - 1

d = ActiveCell.Value

Do Until d = ""

c = c + 1

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
d = ActiveCell.Value

Loop

Cells.Find(What:="Ref signaal [A]", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

r1 = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Target"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
r2 = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = target
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(r2 & ":F" & c)


Range(r1 & ":F" & c).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Arkusz2!$E$21:$F$" & c)

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers

ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = dat & " " & tim & " " & typ

Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: A good start would be not to use `ActiveSheet`. What if user opens the workbook in a different sheet? Well I'll tell you what happens, it will throw a reference error because there's *(likely)* no `Chart1` in that sheet

Comment: Well I've could precised what exactly my code does...It imports data from `.txt` file to the `Sheet2`, sorts data in columns and rows and draws chart from a certain set of data. So that thing with `ActiveSheet` is not that inappropriate IMO.

Comment: I still stand by the fact it's a bad coding habit. `AcitveSheet` can often result in unexpected behaviour. Just create a `Worksheet` object variable and reference a specific worksheet instead. It's even shorter to write `ws1.Range` then `ActiveSheet.Range`

Comment: As @Rawrplus says, you are setting yourself up for bug prone code. More of your code might help. You can loop worksheets in worksheets collection, and charts within a chart collection (if they already exist) ; you can then work with the current worksheet variable for example For ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets: For each cht in ws.Charts............

Comment: Makes sense to me. So: `dim ws1 as worksheet`? And what's next? Can you navigate me how to move and change size of chart?

Comment: Well, I'll edit the question and add my code. And sorry in advance 'cause a lot of it will be just code from recording macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the question you should be asking yourself, instead of selecting (not in the literal `Select` sense) individual specific charts indexed in array-like order, **you should simply loop through all the charts instead** and not worry about indexing at all!

There are two types of charts

1. The Chart sheets
2. The charts embedded to individual worksheets.

I presume you want to deal with the second option here, as there can be multiple charts as indiciated by what you described with `ChartX` in the question.

---

Now with theory out of the way, let's get down to the nitty-gritty!

```
Private Sub loop_through_charts(where as Worksheet)
   If where.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then 'if the sheet has Charts
       Dim cht as ChartObject
       For Each cht in where.ChartObjects
            ' do something
       Next cht
   End If
End Sub
```

The elegance of this is, we can pass an individual `Worksheet` to the procedure, eg.

```
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
 loop_through_charts(ws2)
```

Or even apply this procedure to every sheet

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets
     loop_through_charts(ws)
Next ws
```

---

**EDIT:**

So... upon more info in comments, simply add the following code to the bottom of your import procedure (once the `Chart` is drawn)

> presumably you have variable `ws` referencing the `Worksheet` from import button

```
Dim newestChart As Integer
newestChart = ws.ChartObjects.Count

With ws.ChartObjects(newestChart)
   ' do something
End With
```

Comment: Well, sorry guys, I've made quite an understatement in my question. We're only humans hey. in the sheet there's only one chart at once. Next chart that could appear is when you click "import" and import a file. Then it draws a single chart based on data from it. And if it happens at the same "session", when workbook was not closed before, it automaticly gets name "Chart 2", etc. And when you close it and open again, counter, built in excel, resets, and again we have "Chart 1".

Comment: @dave So, in other words, you just want to do something on latest chart upon it's imported?

Comment: Exactly. Want to move it and resize it.

Comment: And oh, maybe "upon chart is imported" is a bad statement, rather "upon it's drawn". I do not import chart. But I think you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Dave  check my edit, should be fine now (hopefully)

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work, maybe I've failed to copy-paste it, I don't know. There's `object variable or With block variable not set` error in line `newestChart = ws.ChartObjects.Count`

Comment: And hence I don't know how to move and resize it, I pasted in between `With` - `End With` the code I have, with setting color and changing type of line in the second series of data

Comment: `Dim ws As Worksheet`
 `Dim newestChart As Integer`
   `newestChart = ws.ChartObjects.Count`

    `With ws.ChartObjects(newestChart)`
        
      `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select`
   `With Selection.Format.Line`
       `.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)`
    `End With`
    
   `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select`
   `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineMarkers`
    
   `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select`
   `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = dat & " " & tim & " " & typ`
        
    `End With`

Comment: Oh, posting code in comment section is kinda dissapointing...I'll edit it...hope to hear some more help

Comment: And upper here not "hence" but "since"...sorry

Comment: @Dave have you defined your `ws` variable?

Comment: I think so. `Dim ws As Worksheet`

Comment: Yes, but have you set it to anything? eg `Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` - as shown in my code excerpt #2

Comment: Oh, my bad. Now it works perfectly. Now if you could show me some lines to change chart position and its size would be amazing.

Comment: I'd recommend looking up `With` in vba. It would be moot to simply dump the code there, if you wouldn't understand how it works. I'm pretty sure, once you do your research, you'll be even able to write it yourself) :)

Comment: @Dave So, what's the progress? Can this be accepted as an answer or do you need help with anything else? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for not responding. Yes! I've applied your solution and then figured out positioning etc. and now works fine :) Of course I'll accept it.